# Why is zsh returning the difference of two floating point number in engineering notation?

Tags: math, floating-point, zsh

When I subtract certain numbers whose difference is rather small, zsh doesn't output a floating point number like I expect. Instead, it outputs the difference like this:

```
% echo $((-78.44335 - -78.4433))
-5.0000000001659828e-05
```

This is causing unexpected behavior in a script which deals with arbitrary numbers: except when the difference is very small, there is no problem.

Why is zsh doing this? How can I make it always output a normal floating point number instead?

Edit:

My actual application is closer to this:

```
var=$((-78.44335 - -78.4433))
var2=$var
var=$((var * var3))
```

etc.

Comment: From a nitpicker: `zsh` uses "scientific notation".  The term "engineering notation" is often reserved to a particular formatting in which you use only powers of 1000 in the exponent, like in your case "-50.000000001659828e-06"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the engineering notation, this is normal when the exponent ≤ −5, and often the preferred way to represent floating-point numbers. If you don't like that, you can use `printf` with `%f`; for instance:

```
$ printf "%.24f\n" $((-78.44335 - -78.4433))
-0.000050000000001659827831
```

Alternatively, to assign the result to a variable without having to use a command substitution (thus a subshell):

```
$ ((var = -78.44335 - -78.4433))
$ echo $var
-0.0000500000
```

But only 10 digits are output after the decimal point (like `printf "%.10f"`). This may not be sufficient for all applications.

Some additional note about the trailing digits: Floating-point numbers are represented in base 2. This means that when converting a decimal number such as -78.44335 or -78.4433 to base 2, a rounding error generally occurs (because the decimal number cannot be represented exactly in the destination format, generally [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). The effect of rounding errors is what you can see in the output. In particular, when you subtract two inexact numbers that are very close to each other, a [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) occurs, so that the relative error is quite large.

Note: this is not specific to zsh. You'll have similar problems with all software that uses base 2 internally.

Comment: Should have specified this in the question, but I am actually assigning a variable to the value of this arithmetic substitution to perform further operations on it, so printf seems suboptimal (I would have to use a subshell, I guess.). I hadn't heard about catastrophic cancellation, good to know about that.

Comment: @catlover2 Yes, even though `printf` is a builtin, command substitution will start a subshell. But you can do the assignment in the arithmetic expression (see my edited answer). This currently does what you want, but may not be future-proof (I haven't seen any spec that guarantees this behavior).

Comment: It looks like I fell victim to [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). My actual solution is to let zsh do all the math operations in one large expression so that a variable never gets set to these very small values at all. But I'm +1ing and accepting anyway because your solutions works perfectly for what I _asked_. ;)